# Making all the children sleep from another child thread

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, thread-sleep

I am trying to develop a program with POSIX threads in which i have a child thread which will be updating the content of a file and the database between certain intervals and there will be other children who reads data from the file and database all the time. So i don't want any thread to read the file or database while they are being written by the single updater thread. So my idea is to make all other children threads sleep from the child thread which will update the file and database. sleep() makes the calling thread sleep. Is there any way the above scenario can be implemented?!

**EDIT:**

I have two different functions for reading and writing the file. Most of the threads access the read method so they aren't vulnerable but they might be if they try to read in between while the periodic thread which accesses the write method is updating the file's contents.

Comment: It sounds like you don't want a sleep so much as a reader/writer lock or something similar. (Or try to redesign to allow concurrent reading and writing...)

Comment: so r/w locking can only be used to achieve this? i mean is that the only option?

Comment: Well that *sounds* like what you want to me, given your description...

Comment: i am not using a shared variable for reading and writing. that's why i opted for sleep().

Comment: But you're reading and writing from a shared resource - so if you want exclusive access, it sounds like you *should* be using a read/write lock. I haven't done any threading in C before, but in the environments I've worked in you can't force other threads to sleep - and you wouldn't want to (as they may be doing something else which is critical, but has nothing to do with the resource you're trying to guard). Maybe you should add more context to your question.

Comment: @Sudershan You're thinking about threads completely wrong. Any time you feel the need to reach in from the outside to make a thread do what it's supposed to do or stop it from doing something it's not supposed to do, you're thinking about threads wrong. The threads do only what you tell them to do. So code them to do only the right things in the first place and you won't need to find a way to reach in and make them do the right thing or keep them from doing the wrong thing. Focus on the work, not the threads.

Answer (score 2):

You do not want to use `sleep` for this at all.  Instead, use a reader/writer lock.  The updater thread must acquire the lock (in write mode) before it modifies the data.  And the other threads must acquire the lock (in read mode) before reading the data.

Note that if your reader threads are reading continuously, the writer will get starved and never acquire the lock.  So you will need some separate mechanism such as a flag the updater can set that tells the readers to please stop reading and release their locks.  If the readers only read occasionally this shouldn't be such an issue (unless there are tons of readers in which case you may have an architectural problem).